# Laravel Event:fire payload wrong format

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am currently using Laravel 4.2.

When I fire an Event sending the payload as array, listener retrieves the payload with it only being the first item in the associative array.

Firing the event:

```
$data = array('user' => $user, 'password_clear'  => $pass);
Event::fire('user.created', $data);
```

Listening like this:

```
Event::listen('user.created', function($data) {
    dd($data);
}
```

Dumps the following:

```
object(User)#809 (20) {
    ...
}
```

While I would have expected an array. Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Federico

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the contents of $user correctly? Can we see that?

Comment: Well.. $user variable is simply assigned like this:
$user = Auth::user()->load('settings');
Nothing special about that...